# python function for HTTP calls

Tags: python

I have a script that uses a dictionary stored in "my_dict" variable, and values of url, user, password, along with the "id" variable. The script then does an HTTP GET call to the url depending on headers passed. How do I create a Python Function which is equivalent to this? And how to the function later for another set of url, user, password etc?

```
import urllib, urllib2, base64, json

my_dict = {'server': {'user': 'patrick', 'url': 'http://192.168.0.1/tasks', 'password': 'secret'}}

id = "8d4lkf8kjhla8EnsdAjkjFjkdb6lklne"

for value in my_dict.keys():
    url = my_dict[value]['url']
    pass = my_dict[value]['password']
    authKey = base64.b64encode("patrick:"+str(pass))
    headers = {"login-session": id, "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic " + authKey}
    data = {"param": "value"}

    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    for key, value in headers.items():
        request.add_header(key, value)
    response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
    print response
```

Comment: Do you want to create a generic function to send an http request by giving the `dictionary` and `id`, so you can use it in another places too?

Comment: Perhaps you should [learn python](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) at first.

Comment: @chayasan, yes,  i wanted to use the same function later, depending on key values pair in the dictionary. Sorry about the id, it is just a static value for a period.

Comment: thanks miindlek, i am newbie here, still learning some of those basics.. thanks again for the link.

Comment: Then all you have to do is copy the entire `for` loop block and paste it inside a function which will accept your `my_dict` as a parameter. I don't know whether you are asking for something different! :/

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a lot of subquestions such as what do you want variable or constant? Do you know the syntax? How your function will be used? etc etc.

Therefore the best way for you to get an answer is learn some basics, like [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) (*free*) for the functions syntax in python. After that you may very well have the answers to your question.

Comment: Sorry for not describing much. In fact the dictionary will grow eventually with "different" urls but with "same" authentication, headers and credentials. Thanks for the link, going through those tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function like this will work if I understood you correctly,

```
def send_request(my_dict, id):
    for value in my_dict.keys():
        url = my_dict[value]['url']
        pass = my_dict[value]['password']
        authKey = base64.b64encode("patrick:"+str(pass))
        headers = {"login-session": id, "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic " + authKey}
        data = {"param": "value"}

        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        for key, value in headers.items():
        request.add_header(key, value)
        response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
        print response
```